# Why my charAt function is not working on my javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a simple function to be executed every time when one text area is updated, but I want to get the last character of the text in that text area.
In order to do so, I used `charAt`, but then code stopped working.

Please, anyone tell me what is the mistake I made.

```
// array is goes here

function startText() {
    var str=document.getElementById("intxt").value;
    var matchkeyword = str.charAt(str.length-1);
    // code extends

    var sugest = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < consonants.length; i++) {
        if (consonants[i].match(matchkeyword.value) != null && matchkeyword.value != "") {
            sugest = sugest + "<br>" + consonants[i] + "=" + consonantsUni[i];
        }
    }
    y = document.getElementById("sugdiv");
    y.innerHTML = sugest;
}
```

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem describing; tell us what happens. And include the relevant HTML code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After assigning it to a variable like this

```
var matchkeyword = str.charAt(str.length-1);
```

you should not use `value` on `matchkeyword`. Instead of,

```
if(consonants[i].match(matchkeyword.value) != null && matchkeyword.value != "") {
```

use

```
if(consonants[i].match(matchkeyword) != null && matchkeyword != "") {
```

**Note:** If you are using Chrome, whenever the script "stops working", press <kbd>F12</kbd> which will open Developer Tools. You ll be able to get clues from that.